# How to align 2 images on the side of another image using display:inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am tring to align 2 images on the side of another image. Like this.
[image]

This is what I have tried out.

```
 <div class="outerdiv">
    <div class="div1">1</div>
    <div class="div2">2</div>
    <div class="div3">3</div>
</div>

.outerdiv{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:250px;
    text-align:center;
}

.div1,.div2,.div3{
    background:orange;
    margin:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.div1{
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
}

.div2,.div3{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ibsenvalath/jLprpbbb/2/). I am using display:inline-block to align images. I couldnt use float:left as I need to align it in the center.

UPDATE: I am also looking for a responsive design.So all divs will automatically align one below other in mobile devices. So I cant use a wrapper for div2 and div3.

Comment: You could add a wrapper around 2 & 3 and **have** that be inline block with 1.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jLprpbbb/3/ But your numbers in the code don't actually match the example image.

Comment: @Paulie_D, thats nice, but the design should be responsive as well.

Comment: If you wan responsive then your question is too broad. What have you done to solve this yourself?

Comment: @Paulie_D  I tried it using float:left. It was working well, but I couldn't align all 3 divs  in the center of the outer div.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a problem with using tables? Does it have to be `display:inline` exactly? This aligns everything as required, and centres it - if that's what you wanted.

```css
table{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right:-50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="background-color:red;"></td>
    <td style="background-color:blue;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background-color:green;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with tables here, it's not really tabular data. CSS tables maybe but tables for layout...ugh!

Comment: Nice solution, but I cant use tables, as I am building a responsive app.

Comment: Tables aren't best practices anyways for page/DOM alignments!

Answer (score 0):

Add a new wrapper around the two divs as suggested by Paulie and add the property `display: inline-table` for the column.

**HTML**

```
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="one-column">
    <div class="div2">2</div>
    <div class="div3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outerdiv {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:250px;
  text-align:center;
}

.div1, .div2, .div3 {
  background:orange;
  margin:10px;
}

.div1 {
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.one-column {
  display: inline-table;
}

.div2, .div3 {
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/jLprpbbb/4/)

Comment: I  cant use tables, as I am building a responsive app. I have updated my question.

Comment: Check my earlier solution to another question, it uses Bootstrap so you have an idea: http://www.codeply.com/go/mPUM0bIvEH

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, if you want a responsive design, would be go with percentages sizes and absolute positioning

```css
.outerdiv{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:250px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}

.div1,.div2,.div3{
    background:orange;
    position: absolute;
}

.div1{
    width: 66%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.div2,.div3{
    width: 32%;
    height: 48%;
    right: 0px;
}

.div2 {
    top: 0px;
}

.div3 {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
    <div class="div1">1</div>
    <div class="div2">2</div>
    <div class="div3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flex` to do this. `flex` is meant to create these kind of layouts only.

See the below example.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.horizontal {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.verticle {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}
.full-height {
  height: 100%;
}
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
.half-height {
  height: 50%;
}
.half-width {
  width: 50%;
}
.small-padding {
  padding: 5px;
}
.img1 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/400/people/1");
  background-size: cover
}
.img2 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people/2");
  background-size: 100%;
}
.img3 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people/3");
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal flex container">
  <div class="img1 full-height half-width"></div>
  <div class="verticle flex half-width full-height">
    <div class="img2 half-height full-width"></div>
    <div class="img3 half-height full-width"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[FlexBox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add another wrapper inside outerwrap to all 3 divs. And try it out with a display:inline-block; and width set. floats for the inner divs, when the resolution, decreases below your breakpoint, it should align one below the other constrained within the new div.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aL96brqz/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outerdiv">
    <div class="innerdiv">
        <div class="div1">1</div>
        <div class="div2">2</div>
        <div class="div3">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outerdiv {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:250px;
    text-align:center;
}
.innerdiv {
    width: 190px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.div1,.div2,.div3 {
    background:orange;
    margin:10px;
    float: left;
}
.div1 {
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
}
.div2,.div3 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```